# PHP one digit after decimal point for real numbers and no digits for integer values

Tags: php, numbers, digit

What is the best solution to convert a number to:

1. one digit after decimal point if that number is a real number
2. no digits, no decimal point if the number is an integer

Example:

```
if ($num == 8.2) //display 8.2
if ($num == 8.0) //display 8
```

Note: I won't have numbers like 8.22 or 8.02. I will have this type of numbers:

1, 1.2, 1.4 ... 2.6, 2.8, 3 ....9.8, 10

Comment: What should be displayed for 8.02?

Comment: why the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235080/smarty-filter-one-digit-after-decimal-point-integer-exception ?

Comment: @user4035 - Good question! I won't have such numbers, so we can exclude them, but if you ask, you can consider that number a real number so in that case is 8.0. But again, I don't have a problem with that because I won't have that case.

Comment: @nogad - Because that is a smarty question, there are independent smarty filters and less users who use smarty. This is a php question, with php you can build your own filters and also there are many php users. That's the reason.

Comment: Should `8.56` result in `8.5` or `8.6`? (How should rounding be handled)

Comment: @CollinD It doesn't matter. You can use 8.5. I won't have that case. My goal is to remove the dot digit for integers.

Comment: If you decide to downvote the question, please let me know why.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide us even one example of something you tried. How is this not just a request for code?

Comment: @takendarkk true; I was thinking to do IF staff but I knew there must be something better.

Comment: Well, if you have code that works, but just want to improve it, why not ask on codereview.stackexchange?

Comment: @takendarkk - My solution was kinda crap, I knew there must be a better solution that my IF and in the same time I thought that other peoples might get into this same issue and benefit from this question answers also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know for sure that all of your numbers will be in that format, you should be able to just use `round`. (Normally, `round` does *not* work well for formatting, but in this case it should do the job.)

```
foreach ([8, 8.2, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3, 9.8, 10] as $number) {
    echo round($number, 1) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Some might assume otherwise, but `echo round(8.0, 1);` displays `8`, not `8.0`.

Comment: Bro I used ... for the rest of the numbers. I have all the numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I just copied and pasted, and didn't bother filling the other stuff in, but they should all work the same.

Comment: Dude, this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Bro, you are a genius, I waited for you for a long itme.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (abs($num - (int)$num) < 0.001)
  echo (int)$num;
else
  echo number_format($num, 1);
```

Comment: Is this the best option I can use or there are any other more optimized solutions? Mabey 1 line solutions? Without if?

Comment: You can of course write it as a one-liner: `echo (abs($num - (int)$num) < 0.001) ? (int)$num : number_format($num, 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Using floor and some arithmetic and `number_format`

```
$num = 8.0;

//8.0 - 8 = 0
//8.2 - 8 = .2
if($num - floor($num)>0) {
    // Leaves 1 decimal
    echo number_format($num,1);
    // or if rounding
    //echo round($num, 1);
} else {
    // Leaves 0 decimal
    echo number_format($num,0);
    // or if rounding
    //echo round($num, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is this the best option I can use or there are any other more optimized solutions? Mabey 1 line solutions? Without if?

Comment: You are confusing optimization with brevity, There's no real way around the conditional, if you want it in one line, use a ternary operator.

Comment: Well, it seems that this was the solution I was looking for round($number, 1) . PHP_EOL